# Regex in spring boot page controller

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot

I have tried to add the below regex to spring boot page controller. But i got an error

> The number of capturing groups in the pattern segment
>   (^((?!txt$|xml$).)*$) does not match the number of URI template
>   variables it defines, which can occur if capturing groups are used in
>   a URI template regex. Use non-capturing groups instead.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{param:^((?!txt$|xml$).)*$}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(@PathVariable(value = "param") String pageParam, Model model, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException
{
    return pageParam;
}
```

How can i fix this?

I want to exclude the below urls from page controller.

http://localhost:8080/abc.txt and
http://localhost:8080/sitemap.xml

Thanks

Comment: I had changed the regex & its working. {param:(?:(?!txt$|xml$).)*} is it correct?

Comment: It is correct because it works. If the system tells you "Use non-capturing groups instead." this is what you need to do.